# Plotting a list of data containing variables in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a series of variables in gnuplot:

```
x1 = 1 ; y1 = 1
x2 = 2 ; y2 = 2
...
```

And I want to plot them as if they were data points belonging to the same data set `(x1,y1)`, `(x2,y2)`, etc. so that I can perform the same kind of operations on this data set as would be possible if they were given in an external data file (join them with lines, fit a function to them, and so on).

I have tried the special input `"-"`:

```
plot "-"
x1 y1
x2 y2
e
```

but this doesn't work, gnuplot does not recognize the variables' values.

I have had success with a temporary file and `set print`:

```
set print "temp"
print x1, y1, "\n", x2, y2
plot "temp"
```

But this is not a very nice solution. Is there a nicer way to do this? Schematically, I'm after something like:

```
plot {{x1,y1},{x2,y2}} # This doesn't work!
```

Comment: I don't know any better way. Usually `gnuplot` isn't properly useable for such kind of tasks. If you have a lot of variables you have to `print`, you can automate this. But it won't become nicer.